# Filtering HTML comment nodes from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium

I wanted to know if there is a way for filter the innerHTML of a DOM to just contain the actual HTML and discard all the comment nodes?

---

Actually, I'm working with Angularjs and writing some tests with Selenium. And Angular litters the rendered HTML with a lot of comments such as:

```
<!-- ngSwitchWhen: join -->
<div data-ng-switch-when="leave">
  <!-- ngIf: isNow -->
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

I'm trying this currently for matching the result: `@client` is the WebDriver instance.

```
@client.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='log']/li")).getAttribute('innerHTML').then (innerHtml) ->
      html = innerHtml.trim()
      expect(html).to.equal """
        <div class="image"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></div>
        <div class="fade-6 content">Getting more activities...</div>
      """
```

This creates a big problem when I'm trying to test the returned DOM's structure with Mocha. What do I test for? I can't possibly repeat all the useless comments in my **expected value**, that would be immensely wasteful.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment nodes are DOM nodes, as you know. You can iterate over all nodes and filter comments out by their [node type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType):

```
recursivelyIterate(container, function (subNode) {
    if (subNode.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
        subNode.parentNode.removeChild(subNode);
    }
});
```

*(I haven't included the code for `recursivelyIterate` function, but it should be trivial to write one.)*

---

Alternatively, leave them comments be and don't work with DOM nodes, work with DOM elements. `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelectorAll` and friends.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of directly using querySelector* and their ilk. It does my mind at rest, although there are still problems with how the data in the node is written. **There is some text which is wrapped with tags, and some text which is just... text., something like this:** `<div class='node'><span class='wrap1'>Text1</span> is not equal to <span class='wrap2'>Text2</span></div>`
<br><br>
Now when I get the children of `.node` and filter them, I'm getting the nodes, but not the text node with `is not equal to` text. Any pointers?

Comment: @KumarHarsh, just keep in mind you can examine the node type and compare it to one of `Node.COMMENT_NODE`, `Node.TEXT_NODE` and `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`. Both text nodes and element nodes are separate nodes with distinct types.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it seems that the text which is outside a DOM element (div, span, etc) is not a child of it's parent... :?
__Sorry, I'm not able to exactly explain it here, kindly look at this fiddle:__ http://jsfiddle.net/RedDevil/9vVZj/ The text `Shouldn't I be Included` should form a separate DOM node, no?

Comment: You should have used `childNodes` instead of `children` (which are only element nodes). See http://jsfiddle.net/6McQu/

Answer (score 3):

Writing tests that rely on `innerHTML` is not a good idea at all.

When you fetch `innerHTML`, the browser serialises the information in the DOM into a new markup string which is not necessarily the same as the markup that was originally parsed to make the DOM.

Markup details such as:

- what order attributes are in
- what case tags are
- what whitespace there is in tags
- what quotes are used to delimit attribute values
- what content characters are encoded as entity or character references

are not stored in the DOM information set so are not preserved. Different browsers can and will produce different output. In some cases IE even returns invalid markup, or markup that does not round-trip back to the same information set when parsed.

+1 katspaugh's answer demonstrates ways to get the information out of the DOM rather than relying on `innerHTML`, which avoids this problem.

However, more generally, it is usually a bad idea to write tests that depend strongly on the exact markup your application uses. This is too-tight coupling between the requirements in the test and the implementation details. And any little change you make to the markup for even a trivial stylistic reason or textual update means you have to update all your tests to match. Tests are a useful tool to catch things that you didn't mean to break; tests that always break on every change are giving you no feedback on whether you broke something so are non-useful.

Whilst there's generally no magic bullet to separate tests completely from application markup, generally you should reduce the test to the minimum that satisfies the user's requirement, and add signalling to catch those cases. I don't know what exactly your app is doing but I would guess the requirement is something like: "When the user clicks the 'more' button, a busy-spinner should appear to let them know the information is being fetched".

To test this you might do a check like "does the element with id 'log' contain an element with class 'icon-refresh'?". If you wanted to be more specific that it's a spinner to do with fetching activities, you could add a class like "refresh-activities" to the "Getting more activities..." div, and detect the element with that class instead of relying on text which is likely to change (especially if you ever translate your app).